# com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam - Cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jersey

I have included all jars from the Apache Jersey distribution zip however this import cannot be resolved:

```
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;
```

What specific jar does this it need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the jersey-multipart.jar file?

Comment: Just added it, and the error in code is fixed. However I'm getting lots of error when running the code though.

Comment: Per [Jersey's documentation](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html#d4e1818): do you also have the mimepull.jar (as it sounds like you're not using a mavenized environment)

Comment: This jar isn't available in common maven repositories, though.